# Deploy pyramid app with uwsgi and apache

Tags: apache, uwsgi

I have a pyramid app in a virtualenv, and I want to deploy it using apache+uwsgi, but I don't figure how to connect apache, uwsgi and pyramid. Can anyone provide an apache.conf and production.ini example?

In many examples you should create an init script to manage the uWSGI process, but can apache start the uwsgi process?

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with the Apache side of things, but here's my uwsgi config.ini that would work in your case.  Apache does not support the native uwsgi protocol, so you will need to configure uwsgi to speak http as below.  Then, Apache will need to be configured to proxy requests to a backend http server.

> http = 127.0.0.1:33932   ;also could use unix file socket
>
> master = 1
>
> workers = 5   ;number of cpus + 1
>
> harakiri = 30  ;seconds = request timeout length
>
> buffer-size = 32768   ; found experimentally.  Your app may work well with less or more.
>
> chdir = /path/to/your/uwsgi_webapp
>
> module = your_module
>
> callable = your_wsgi_app
>
> virtualenv = /path/to/your/uwsgi_webapp/env
>
> daemonize = /path/to/your/uwsgi_webapp/log/uwsgi.log
>
> pidfile = /path/to/your/uwsgi_webapp/uwsgi_fuzzy.pid

Note that using Apache as a front-end webserver is not a recommended configuration.  Starting up a complete Apache process just to proxy to another http server will result in fairly poor performance.  For that reason, a lightweight server like nginx or a http proxy like Varnish is preferred.